# TableView height change while scrolling resets contentOffset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I encountered an animation flicker that occurs when dragging down a `UITableView`.  If the height of a UITableView changes during a 'rubber banding' drag, the `contentOffset` gets set to the `contentInset` when the table height change animation completes.

Here's a project reproducing the issue, as well as a bad work around.  If you drag the table down, you should see the table contents flicker back to the top momentarily.

Anyone have any ideas for a better workaround?

https://github.com/KingOfBrian/AppleBugs/blob/master/ContentOffsetBug/ContentOffsetBug/RZViewController.m